# Extract big field from json document without having it all in memory

Tags: python, flask-restful

I have a flask API that accepts json with the fields

```
{"nonce": int, "data_blob": str, "original_hash": str, "last_modify_ts": int}
```

and my issue is that `data_blob` can be big in the order of `>=500mb`. I want to read this field of the document and store it in a file without having all the json in memory.

For reading the data raw data I can read the request data but I'm not sure how to chunk it in a way that allows me to store the field as I read the data. What would a way to be reading the json and store only in a file this field while keeping the others in memory?

I can't use a streamed request due to backward compatibility.

Comment: [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) ?